# If $H_1 (X)$ is free abelian, then $\pi_1 (X)$ is free?

Tags: algebraic-topology

We know that for a path connected space $X$, $\pi_1 (X)/(\pi_1 (X))'\cong H_1 (X)$. Trivially, if $\pi_1 (X)$ is free, then $H_1$ is free abelian. Does the converse hold too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The trivial counterexample is whenever $\pi_1(X)$ is free abelian of rank $>1$. Since free abelian is not free when rank $>1$. But it is equal its abelianization (which is true for any abelian group). For example the torus.

But there's more. Every non-trivial, non-free, [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group) $\pi_1(X)$ is a counterexample. For example the alternating group $A_5$, which is finite non-trivial, and thus not free. Together with the fact that any group is realizable as a fundamental group of some space, even CW complex. In such case $H_1(X)=0$ is free abelian.

To obtain free abelian $H_1(X)$ of arbitrary rank you can take the previous example and apply wedge sum with circles. In this situation original $X$ being CW complex is important to calculate the fundamental group and homology of the wedge sum. The first one translates to free product (which is not free if one of the components is not free), while the second one to direct sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect explanation. I got it completely. Appreciate your help.